# Dart: Return string value from list of maps

Tags: dart

I have a list of maps with enums and strings.

```dart
enum orderType {
  Buy,
  Sell,
}

List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [
  { 'orderType': orderType.Buy, 'stockName': 'ABCD' },
  { 'orderType': orderType.Sell, 'stockName': 'EFGH' },
];
```

Now how do I get the `stockName` from any map in the list if have access to the order type?

```dart
String getStockName(selectedOrderType) {
  // return items.where((item) => item['orderType'] == selectedOrderType).toList();
}
```

Comment: You want to use `items.entries` to iterate over the `Map`: `items.entries.where(...).toList()`.  You also presumably want to return a `List<String>` instead of a `String`.

Comment: @jamesdlin I don't want to return List, I only want to return the string value of `stockName` key.

Comment: Then you'll need to do something like `items.entries.where(...).first.key`, assuming that a matching entry is guaranteed to be found. (Or check that `.where(...)` returns a non-empty result first.) That said, what you're doing doesn't seem like it makes much sense: can `items` not contain multiple buy orders or multiple sell orders for the same stock?  If `items` can only contain a single buy order and a single sell order, then you might as well use `Map<orderType, String>` instead to map `orderType` directly to a stock name.

Comment: @jamesdlin if you are using `where(...).first` you are just better to use`firstWhere` and handle the `onElse` function